# Multiple Exchange Mailboxes to One AD Account

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010

Is it possible to have multiple Exchange 2010 mailboxes to one Active Directory account?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as far as i know you can only have one primary mail address, but using the full access-permission on a mailbox, the user with that permission can use the mailbox much like his primary mailbox. Outlook will even automatically map the full access mailbox(es), so that you can see and use all of them without additional configuration (at least, if you didn't turn off that feature previously).

So you can create a new mailbox in Exchange 2010 and provide the user in question with full access to that mailbox.